# toggle tr of table not working

Tags: jquery

[Here is my demo code](http://alachiq.ir/samples/table/)

I want to disable `td` with this content 'CLICKING MUST BE DISABLE' and clicking on 'CLICK HEAR 1' works correctly but is not working 'CLICK HEAR 2'

JQUERY:

```
$("#chart tr:odd").addClass("odd");

$("#chart tr.odd").click(function()
    {
  $(this).next("tr").toggle();
});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="chart">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td height="25" width="200px"><b>TABLE 1</b>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="6">CLICKING MUST BE DISABLE</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr class="odd">
        <td style="padding-right: 30px;" width="100px"></td>
        <td style="background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237);" width="200px">CLICK HEAR 1</td>
        <td height="25">
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr style="display: none;">
       <td></td>
       <td colspan="4">
                 sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>   
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td height="25" width="200px"><b>TABLE 2</b>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="6">CLICKING MUST BE DISABLE</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-right: 30px;" width="100px"></td>
        <td style="background-color: rgb(237, 237, 237);" width="200px">CLICK HEAR 2</td>
        <td height="25">
        </td>
    </tr>   
    <tr class="odd" style="display: none;">
       <td></td>
       <td colspan="4">
                 sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>sssss<br>   
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `:odd` selector but the row you want to select is not an odd row.

1. Clicking must be disabled
2. Click here 1
3. Clicking must be disabled
4. Click here 2

The following jsFiddle shows a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2rDww/

I have manually added the `odd` class to the two rows that should be clickable. You can remove the first line that adds the odd class to all the odd rows.

Comment: @ Wouter de Kort , thanks, i can click on `Clicking must be disabled` second of table and `Click here 2` not working

Comment: Updated the jsFiddle link.. don't know why the previous one didn't contain my changes.

Answer (score -1):

This is your HTML (simplified):

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td>CLICK HEAR 1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>CLICK HEAR 2</td>
</tr>
```

This is your click function

```
$("#chart tr.odd").click(function() {
    $(this).next("tr").toggle();
});
```

It's looking for all the `tr`'s with class `odd` : The first `tr` in your HTML has it, but your second doesn't (that why it's not working). You try to add those classes through JavaScript with the:

```
$("#chart tr:odd").addClass("odd");
```

But that's applied **after** the click handler.

Solution could be that you would add the `odd` class to your second `tr`, but most dynamic one would be to simply change your selector to use the `odd` filter instead of the class:

```
$("#chart tr:odd").click(function() {
    $(this).next("tr").toggle();
});
```

Ps. It's "*here*", not "*hear*" ;) .

Comment: This is not going to work. The clickable row is not an odd row. This will make the 'Clicking must be disabled' clickable.